# Rails, two part of string one is text and second is attached variable.error occur to display part one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets consider the string "My name is #{@user.name}"
So i need to check and handle the error in this part "#{@user.name}".
Error may be because of "#{user.name}" (user object is undefined) or "#{other_object.name}" 
or accessing the attribute that does not belong to the user table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
name = "#{object.name}" if object.respond_to?(:name)
```

If `object` doesn't respond to `#name` method (it also handles the case when `object` is `nil`), `nil` will be assigned to `name` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"My name is #{@user.try(:name)}"
```

TRY method will return nil if it caught exception, it wont throw any error.

Comment: Using `try` will save you if you call a method on a `nil` object, but you will get an exception if `@user` object doesn't have `name` method/attribute. And OP asked to handle this case as well.

Comment: nope.. even if you try with a method/attribute that is not available, it will return as `nil` rather than throwing exception.

Comment: No, it won't. Try `3.try(:name)`.

Comment: You can also see it from the [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.8/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L32-38). Though, looks like things will change a bit in Rails 4.0 and we'll have two methods: [`try`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L33-39) that returns `nil` if the object doesn't implement the method and [`try!`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L43-49) that throws `NoMethodError` like `try` does in v3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Simple error handling

```
begin
  string = "My name is {@user.name}"
rescue
  string = "My name is not currently available"
end
```